# Duplicate product issue in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, url-rewrite

I am facing some issue with product url when i duplicate product. In detail,

Existing Product: Existing_product
Duplicate Product : Duplicate_product

After duplicating(clicking on "Duplicate" of Existing_product) the product , i changed Name,Sku and other attributes(except URL) and saved the product.

Now the url key of Duplicate_product is showing correctly in the backend but it is different on frontend.

Existing Product's URL: www.website.com/store/existing_product.htm
Duplicated Product's URL: www.website.com/store/existing_product_1.htm
(which should be www.website.com/store/duplicate_product.htm)

Moreover www.website.com/store/existing_product_1.htm redirects to correct product that is duplicated product.

If it is not clear ,let me know.

Can anyone help in this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The url can be set separately from the sku, so maybe you forgot to change it?

Or the most common problem is that you have to rebuild your url index.
Goto `System` / `Index Management` and `rebuild url rewrites`

Comment: I have changed the skus also. And "Catalog URL Rewrites" index in stuck on processing.

Comment: try to run it from the commandline, open a shell, browse to `{magentodir}/shell` and `php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url`. Also check your Magento logs if something strange pops up.

Comment: Any other option other than command line as i dont have shell access?

Comment: There can be a problem when indexing in big stores, so shell access would help a lot. You could see what's in your `var/log/exception.log` with your favorite ftp-client. Or contact your hosting provider and ask them to do it.

Comment: I will try this and will let you know.